# Trying to echo PHP variable in HTML input text

Tags: php, html, echo

I can't change the variable because this is how I receive it from a mail server using IMAP.

```
$sender = '"Smith, John"';
```

This is my html:

```
<td>To:</td>
<td><input name="To" id="to" type="text" size="80" onfocus="changeBg('to','#FFF')"
value= <?php echo $sender; ?> /></td>
```

this is the output I get:

```
 To: Smith,John     />
```

How can I escape the " " or what should I do to remove the "/>" at the end of the output? I've tried every example I found on the net and nothing works. Can please anyone give me help?

I want the text just to be in the input text box like this:

```
To: Smith, John
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

When I try the following it works, but the input is not closed at the end(/>)

```
 <td><input name="To" id="to" type="text" size="80" onfocus="changeBg('to','#FFF')"
 <?php echo 'value='.$sender; ?>" </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the value with quotes:

```
<td><input name="To" id="to" type="text" size="80" onfocus="changeBg('to','#FFF')" value="<?php echo $sender; ?>" /></td>
```

Also, wrap the sender value with `addslashes()`

Comment: I tried that but I get an empty input field and at the end (outside the text field) " />

Comment: There must be some more to the story. Here you can see it in action: http://codepad.org/FdOJWG5c

Comment: From the link you sent me, the variable is closed in quotes. Mine is '"name"'... Also did a edit...